# Transformation of dependent variable

Tags: regression, data-transformation, independence

Why do we sometimes transform the dependent variable in a regression analysis as a growth rate?

$$\frac{Y_{it+1}-Y_{it}}{Y_{it}} = X'_i \beta + \epsilon_i$$
instead of:

$$Y_i = X'_i \beta + \epsilon_i$$

Could you tell me when we should use the growth rate and why?

Comment: Usually you use it when it's the quantity you are interested in.

Comment: For example, are there any problems if I run OLS with the amount of GDP instead of the growth rate of GDP on regressors? What is required to regressors in each case?

Comment: Nothing extra or special is required of the regressors.